What's the meaning of 'their' here

With regard to content clauses, generative-transformational grammars have not much surpassed studies of traditional grammars, particularly in their semantic explorations.

Whats the meaing of 'their' in "in their sementic exploratons"?
I think 'generative-transformational grammars'.
Edit note:
A thesis from a non-native speaker of English.
https://s-space.snu.ac.kr/bitstream/10371/85537/1/4.%202236705.pdf

traditional grammars

It is ambiguous.

I think 'generative' didn't surpass 'traditional'. Where(In what field) didn't they? In their exploration. I think 'their' is reasonable to refer to 'generative'.

Whichever way, it means that with regard to content clauses, particularly in the matter of semantic explorations, generative-transformational grammars are not much better than studies of traditional grammars. I suspect the text was not written by a native speaker.

'Generative' surpassed 'traditional', but not by much.

Source? Citations without attribution is  plagiarism.

It's spelled non-native, and only now you're saying the piece was written by someone whose first language is not English? That's an essential piece of information that should have been  included from the start. Please give the title of the thesis and the name of the author. It's still plagiarism without proper attribution.

I added the link after re-searching it.

I’m voting to close this question because it needs detail or clarity. Are you asking, “What is the antecedent of their?”

Yes the antecedent of 'their'

The question:
How do we interpret their in this sentence:

With regard to content clauses, generative-transformational grammars have not much surpassed studies of traditional grammars, particularly in their semantic explorations.

The answer:
Technically, this is ambiguous. But in practice the meaning is the same however we interpret this particular word.
Technically, their can refer to either generative-transformational grammars, or to traditional grammars. Furthermore, there is no obvious basis for deciding that one or the other interpretation is more likely.
But in practice, this suggests that in fact the intention was to refer to both kinds of grammar at the same time. The whole point of the sentence is to compare two types of grammar, and in particular to compare their semantic explorations of content clauses.
In other words, we have two categories:

traditional grammars, and their semantic explorations...
generative-transformational grammars, and their semantic explorations...

And both are in view in this sentence.

The sentence, taken in isolation, does not seem designed for easy comprehension, and the reference of "their" is pretty ambiguous, but it seems to be either to generative-transformational grammars or to both generative-transformational grammars and the traditional grammars both.
I suppose it might depend on whether both categories of grammar engage in "semantic explorations".
I assume most people with a license to read on such erudite matters might know whether they all do or not.

I think it was (1) not written by a native speaker (2) intended to boost an academic's paper count.

@MichaelHarvey well spotted. See the OP's recent edit.
